# window.open() with google hangouts link in flask application

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new tap with a google hangouts link using javascript and window.open(). The link starts with 'meet.google.com' and not with http:// or https://. Adding http:// or https:// infront does lead to an 500 error. But if I launch a link without http:// or https:// infront, my flask application thinks it is a local link and hence I end up with 'http://localhost:5000/meet.google.com'? Any idea how to solve this?

Using https:// does open a new window and everything looks correct, but it does show a google error message. If I just reload the page it works. It seems to me I need to specify something about the window to satisfy google, but I am not sure what?

Comment: why would it http[s] lead to a 500 error if it's a valid URL?

Comment: A url has to start with either http or https. Adding one will not cause an error if the URL is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Because I can't comment, I will respond with an answer.
If the problem is only with `localhost`, the answer is simple. Go to `localhost:<your port>`. You will notice that there is no https header. This is because localhost is local. Thus, your application will work out of the local scope, but as long as you use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, https will not work. I am not sure if this is for everyone, but for me, going to `http://localhost` just redirects to `localhost`.